# Cakephp - Internal server error on file upload using fileupload plugin

Tags: php, cakephp, file-upload, croogo

I am working on a cakephp project (Croogo version).Here user can add attachment to there order. But I am facing issue with attachment. I am using this [Plugin](http://demo.tutorialzine.com/2013/05/mini-ajax-file-upload-form/) for adding attachment. This works fine for me on my local system but throws error online site.

Here is the error

> An Internal Error Has Occurred.

I dont know why this is happening. Please help me out with this.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you check application and server logs against this issue? There will be an answer.

Comment: "An Internal Error Has Occurred." means one of 1. Read the error message in the log files 2. enable debug and read the error message in your browser.

Comment: Log file is empty and debug mode is ON but still its shows me the same error message.Does not give me detailed error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved by Commenting the validation from the model used for uploading and checking validation.
Here is my code :

> var $validate = array(
>           'order_id' => array(
>               'numeric' => array(
>                   'rule' => array('numeric'),
>                   'message' => 'Order Id must be number',
>                   //'allowEmpty' => false,
>                   //'required' => false,
>                   //'last' => false, // Stop validation after this rule
>                   //'on' => 'create', // Limit validation to 'create' or 'update' operations
>               ),
>           )
>           /*
>           'attachement' => array(
>               'uploadError' => array(
>                   'rule' => 'uploadError',
>                   'message' => 'The cover image upload failed.',
>                   'allowEmpty' => TRUE,
>               ),
>               'mimeType' => array(
>                   'rule' => array('mimeType', array('image/gif', 'image/png', 'image/jpg', 'image/jpeg', 'image/bmp', 'image/x-icon', 'application/pdf', 'application/powerpoint', 'application/msword', 'application/rtf', 'text/plain', 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document', 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation','application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet','application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text','application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.spreadsheet','application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.presentation','application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.image')),
>                   'message' => 'Please only upload Word Documents, Powerpoints, Adobe Reader Files (PDF), Images.',
>                   'allowEmpty' => TRUE,
>               ),
>               'fileSize' => array(
>                   'rule' => array('fileSize', '<=', '7MB'),
>                   'message' => 'Cover image must be less than 7MB.',
>                   'allowEmpty' => TRUE,
>               ),
>               'processCoverUpload' => array(
>                   'rule' => 'processCoverUpload',
>                   'message' => 'Unable to process cover image upload.',
>                   'allowEmpty' => TRUE,
>               ),
>           ),  */
>       );

and the function for uploading file.

> public function processCoverUpload($check = array()) {
>           $remove_these = array(' ','`','"','\'','\','/');
>           $file_name = $check['attachement']['name'];
>           $file_name = str_replace($remove_these, '', $file_name);
>           $path_parts = pathinfo($file_name);
>           $file_name = $path_parts['filename'].'_'.time().'.'.$path_parts['extension'];
>           $directory      = date('Y/m/');
>           $upload_path    = 'uploads'.DS.'attachments'.DS.$directory;
>           $upload_dir     = WWW_ROOT.$upload_path;

```
    if(!file_exists($upload_dir)) mkdir($upload_dir, 0755, true);

    if (!is_uploaded_file($check['attachement']['tmp_name'])) {
        return FALSE;
    }
    if (!move_uploaded_file($check['attachement']['tmp_name'], $upload_dir.$file_name)) {
        return FALSE;
    }
    $this->data[$this->alias]['attachement'] = $upload_path.$file_name;

    return true;
}
```

I commented the above and did validation in my controller.

Comment: So you've overwritten framework mechanism rather than checking what the error was? Not a good way to go...